# Export/compile multiple org-mode files from separate directories

Tags: org-mode

I am writing my dissertation in Emacs org-mode and have a few questions that hopefully someone has faced before. **Background info**: I have each chapter in a separate directory organized in a .org file that is eventually exported into a PDF. In the chapter directory, there are appropriate subdirectories that have figures *etc.* In each chapter I have the appropriate LaTeX headers and Class declarations to obtain the export to my liking.

**Problem**: Each chapter has page numbers that start at 1,2,3, *etc.*

I would like to customize the page numbers in each chapter so that if CH 1 finishes on page 15, CH 2 begins on page 16. In an ideal world, the export of all .org files would result in a final pdf with sequential page numbers. Is this possible with multiple .org files in *separate* directories? I like organizing the .org files into separate directories as I can easily work on separate chapters where all the figures are self-contained. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: IMO you should not worry about page numbers. Do each chapter individually. Once you are all done, then use a master org file to `#+INCLUDE` all the chapters and export that.

Comment: Any possibility where you can point me to a minimally working example? I would like to try this and tinker with it...

Comment: I just googled "org mode thesis" - I glanced at the [first result](https://github.com/dangom/org-thesis): it looks reasonable and it should be helpful.